# The default location of where Postgresql gets installed?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I was just trying to install Postgresql and Django. I'm looking to change the default database from sqlite to Postgresql (need to find it's bin to change some credentials), but I need to find the location of where Postgresql is installed. I did a normal download/install of it, but I forgot the location.

Is there a way to search for this using a command? Or is its path always default to where it gets installed?

Comment: Can you access postgres via your terminal? i.e. if you type `psql` does it enter the postgres terminal?

Comment: Yes it does go into the postgres terminal

Comment: Per Alex below, you don't actually need to know where PostgreSQL stores its files.  PostgreSQL is a server database; you connect to it over a port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

postgrsql appears to being found at /usr/lib/postgresql on my system, Ubuntu Wheezy.

create a user and assign ownership of the DB:

```
su - postgres

createuser -P  

createdb --owner [user_you_just_created] [db_name]
```

You can also use the postgres user, by default there is no password. To change the postgres user's password:

```
su - postgres

psql -U postgres

ALTER USER postgres with password 'my-secure-password';
```

Comment: I have Mavericks, is it the same thing?

Comment: actually looks like /usr/lib/postgres, updateded my response. DB actually lives at /var/lib/postgres

Comment: go to /lib but postgres was not there.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I don't want to change my user and password if I can use the default credentials. But I don't know what the defaults are.

Comment: I want to know the credentials of user and password. If there is no defaults, I would like to change/make credentials.

Comment: user 'postgres' with no password is default

Comment: the 'createuser -P' command that I posted before is used to create an new user, then use 'createdb'  with the '--owner' argument to set owner to the user you would like

Comment: Please edit your answer with that new information so I can choose it as the answer to my question.

Comment: I just wanted to know the defaults, that is all.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to change your `DATABASES` setting within your `settings.py`.

Change it to:

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
            'NAME': 'mydb', # Use whatever your database name is here
            'USER': 'myuser',
            'PASSWORD': 'password',
            'HOST': 'localhost', 
            'PORT': '', 
        }
    }
```

If you don't have a proper postgres database setup yet, then on your terminal type:

```
createdb mydb
```

This will create a new database named 'mydb'. You can change the name to whatever you want, just make sure you make it correspond in your `settings.py`.

Django docs on `DATABASE` setting [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases).

Comment: I don't know my user and password, which is why I was looking for the bin to change them.